# What are these white dots around my wheel?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I just started blender and wonder what are these white circles around my wheel.[image: se]

Comment: Those are particles, you added a particle system

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Those are particles, you added a particle system.

<sup>*[Duarte Farrajota Ramos](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/19307), 2020*</sup>

To remove it ...

1. select the object
2. go to the [Properties Area](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/properties_editor.html)
3. go to the [Particle Settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/particle_system_panel.html#particle-system-panel)
4. click on the "-" symbol to remove the particle system.

[image: particle settings]